# Resize a plot generated in R in a web page generated by blogdown to different screen size

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

- **Antecedent 1**: A static hugo page generated by the blogdown R package.
- **Antecedent 2:** A blog post created from a rmarkdown document with R plots.
- **Question:** Some way to resize a plot produced by a chunk of R code in a rmarkdown post when I open the page from a mobile phone?

For example, all the content of this [post](http://alkzar.cl/post/a-post-example/) is resize when I open from my mobile except the plot. How can achieve something like [that](https://simplystatistics.org/2017/04/06/huelga/)?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to resize images according to the available screen width is to set this CSS rule:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yihui in the subdirectory public/css/main.css just add the above rule?

Comment: No, you should never touch `public/`. It is automatically generated from source. The `css/main.css` is either in your theme, or under `static/` of your root directory. If you are not sure, edit the one in your theme.